# Why does printing struct members result in gibberish?

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I am trying to print and access members of a struct in order to use some of the data contained within.

I have two structs, the first of which is a binary search tree and contains duplicate keys. I am trying to extract the unique keys and store them in a separate struct.

**Note:** I am able to print all unique keys out of `node` structure from within `unique_key` function. However I need access to these unique keys from within the main. Thus my idea was to create a separate struct and pass this back to the main function.

Defining both structs:

```
/* structure containing duplicate keys */
struct node
{
    int KEY;
    char *command;
    char *duration; /* pointer to a char since it is of unknown size*/
    char *time;
    char *description;
    int count;
    struct node *left, *right;
};

/* structure to hold unique keys*/
 typedef struct {
    int KEY;
    char *command;
    char *duration; /* pointer to a char since it is of unknown size*/
    char *time;
    char *description;
 }unique;
```

I am using a utility function to traverse of the binary search tree. This function is supplied with a pointer to the binary search tree `*root` and prints all the unique keys.

```
/* A utility function to find deepest keys of BST */
/* This is done by extracting the key with the lowest count, 
since count member of node struct gets incremented each time it is read. */
unique* unique_key(struct node *root)
{   
    unique *temp = (struct unique *)malloc(sizeof(unique));
    if (root != NULL)
    {
        unique_key(root->left);
        if (root->count == 1) {
            //the printf statement below prints all unique keys
            //Somehow I need to access in the main function, thus my idea was to create a separate struct as explained above
            printf("%d(%d) -> %s %s %s %s \n", root->KEY, root->count, root->command, root->time, root->duration, root->description);
            temp->KEY = root->KEY;
            temp->command = root->command;
            temp->description = root->description;
            temp->duration = root->duration;
        }
        unique_key(root->right);
    }

    return temp;
}
```

Main driver code:

```
int main()
{
    /* Let us create following BST.  Passing values along with key */
    struct node *root = NULL;
    root = insert_node(root, 12, "C", "1200", "79", "Meeting");
    root = insert_node(root, 3, "C", "1300", "60", "Lunch");
    root = insert_node(root, 2, "C", "1400", "30", "Dinner");
    root = insert_node(root, 1, "C", "0600", "90", "Work");
    root = insert_node(root, 5, "C", "4300", "30", "Diyoor");
    root = insert_node(root, 7, "C", "5608", "30", "Dinner");
    root = insert_node(root, 9, "C", "1409", "35", "t");
    root = insert_node(root, 2, "C", "1600", "60", "play");
    root = insert_node(root, 2, "U", "1800", "88", "eve");

    printf("Inorder traversal of the given tree \n");
    inorder(root);  //prints all keys and subsequent values
    unique *data = NULL;
    data = unique_key(root); //prints only unique keys
    printf("%d %s\n", data[1].KEY, data[1].command); //cannot print keys in main function to access from here on
}
```

A sample output would be as follows. The BST is populated accordingly and all traversal functions work well.

```
Inorder traversal of the given tree
1(1) 2(3) 2(2) 2(1) 3(1) 5(1) 7(1) 9(1) 12(1)
Deepest unique keys of the given tree
1(1) -> C 0600 90 Work
2(1) -> U 1800 88 eve
3(1) -> C 1300 60 Lunch
5(1) -> C 4300 30 Diyoor
7(1) -> C 5608 30 Dinner
9(1) -> C 1409 35 t
12(1) -> C 1200 79 Meeting


-33686019  å, æ
```

Sometimes other gibberish characters appear which are not displayed above.

My question is: How can I print and access the members of `unique` and why am I seeing gibberish? Any suggestions would be appreciated.

---

**EDIT:**

These are the unique keys that I am trying to hold in `unique`:

```
1(1) -> C 0600 90 Work
2(1) -> U 1800 88 eve
3(1) -> C 1300 60 Lunch
5(1) -> C 4300 30 Diyoor
7(1) -> C 5608 30 Dinner
9(1) -> C 1409 35 t
12(1) -> C 1200 79 Meeting
```

I expected `printf("%d %s\n", data[1].KEY, data[1].command);` to return `2 U`.

Comment: It looks like your `unique_key` function is returning a pointer to a single `unique` struct, but you're accessing the first element of it.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @ahota. My initial thoughts were that I was passing all unique keys and not just a single struct. Hence why I wrote `[1]` I was trying to access the second element.

Comment: The return type of `unique_key` is incorrect. It should be `unique* unique_key(...)`. `typedef` works like `typedef <type> <name>` so the type is `struct { .... }` and the name is `unique`. This *probably* won't cause an error since pointers are generally the same size, but it's good to make the types line up. Compiler warnings should have warned about that.

Comment: @Schwern, correct! Thanks for pointing out, edited. Also, compiler did not warn against that. I'm using VS...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, your code steps through the tree and is able to print it fine, but you don't actually collect any of the results when calling unique_key inside itself, and your return type isn't sufficient for returning a list of things (a list needs an end, either a size variable, or a null termination). You need to change your code to actually collect the results. One way to do this would be to use a basic vector (self expanding array), like so:

```
struct MyVector {
  void **data;
  size_t head;
  size_t size;
};
MyVector new_MyVector(size_t initial_size)
{
  MyVector list = {
    .data = malloc(sizeof(void*) * initial_size),
    .head = 0,
    .size = initial_size,
  };
  return list;
}
void push_MyVector(MyVector *vec, unique *item)
{
  if (vec->head <= vec->size) {
    vec->data = realloc(*vec->data)
    vec->size *= 2;
  }
  vec->data[vec->head] = item;
  vec->head++;
}
```

then use it like so

```
unique* unique_key(struct node *root, MyVector *list) {
  ...
  unique *left = unique_key(root->left);
  push_MyVector(list, left)
  ...
  unique *right = unique_key(root->right);
  push_MyVector(list, right)
  ...
}
```

Some notes: Because data is a double pointer, to free the vector, you need to iterate through it and free every individual item. I chose to make data a double pointer to make your current code mostly compatible, but it would be better to make it a single pointer, and directly make your function write to the vector. Also not implemented is expanding the vector so you don't run out of space, though with head and size defined, you can do that (just look up how to use realloc).

PS: this code is all untested but I hope you get the general idea

Comment: What is `UniqueVector list` representing here? Where is it defined?

Comment: Sorry, was a typo, should be MyVector

Answer (score 1):

In C arrays are indexed from 0, not 1. By trying to access `data[1]` You're accessing garbage right after your data. The printf needs to use `data[0]` not `data[1]`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, so it is not possible to return all unique keys with the code I represent above?

Comment: Or even better (as data is not an array) use `data->…`

Comment: Still trying to understand exactly what you're trying to do so I can help, but accessing data[1] is always undefined behavior, just because you're calling malloc multiple times isn't gonna turn them into an array

Comment: @Rrz0 your `unique_key` function doesn't actually create an array of `unique` objects. It just creates one. You'll have to `malloc(n * sizeof(unique))` and fill out each one. To be safe, `n` might be the total number of nodes in your tree to pass the case where they're all unique.

Comment: @neonfuz I edited question to make clearer. Understood ahota, will try to implement. Thanks!

Comment: @Rrz0 You're recursing with `unique_key(root->left);` and `unique_key(root->right);` but you're throwing out the result. You likely need to pass a pointer to an array into each call to accumulate the unique keys. Then when the recursion exits, return the array.